# Eine Begrüßung für Frauen am Weltfrauentag

Tags: salutation

Gibt es in Deutsch eine bestimmte Begrüßung für Frauen am Weltfrauentag?

In meinem Heimatland sagt man etwas, dass

> Herzlichen Glückwunsch zum Geburtstag!

gleicht. Aber das passt in Deutsch nicht.

Oder gibt es in Deutschland keine besondere Begrüßung am Weltfrauentag?

Comment: Weltfrauentag is a day where women celebrate their fight is not over yet. So any sign of appreciation from men may be seen as poking fun at them.

Comment: Auch auf keinen Fall darf man den Weltfrauentag mit dem Muttertag verwechseln.

Comment: Ich habe nichts gesagt über Muttertag

Comment: Glückwünsche sind in Deutschland nur zum Muttertag üblich aber nicht zum Weltfrauentag.

Comment: @Janka a greeting can also raise awareness around. Just like those moments when you say "happy birthday" and everyone that doesn't know fells that they should ask "aww.. It's your birthday today?". At least this is why I'm asking.

Comment: "Okay, there's one Weltfrauentag in a year, and 364 world men's days."

Comment: To be specific, in Germany Weltfrauentag is important to women's rights activists only. Most women do not care. Most men don't even know the date. And you are expected to show appreciation on *any* day of the year, that is.

Comment: You're right! every body should know that discrimination is at home and not on a distant land. But also  it would be kind of awkward to say every/any other day a salutation meant for a cause outside of its context.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Spezielle Begrüßungen für den [**Weltfrauentag**](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationaler_Frauentag) gibt es in Deutschland keine. Viele Männer wissen zwar, dass es diesen Tag gibt, 
aber nicht, dass es der 8. März ist. Das erfährt »Mann« in der Regel nur, wenn im Radio, Fernsehen oder sonstigen Medien davon gesprochen wird.

In verschiedenen Ländern (z. B. in Russland und der Ukraine) ist dieser Tag ein gesetzlicher Feiertag, im deutschsprachigen Raum wird hingegen gearbeitet.

Eine Frau zum Weltfrauentag zu beglückwünschen ist unüblich und wäre insofern deplatziert, als dieser Tag seinen Ursprung in der Unterdrückung und Benachteiligung des weiblichen Geschlechts hat und dies auch heute noch symbolisiert.

Comment: Du willst wohl sagen, dass der Tag indirekt seinen Ursprung i.d. Unterdrückung hat, als diese Anlass zur Auflehnung war, die wiederum zum WFT geführt hat. Dass der Tag seinen Ursprung i.d. Unterdrückung hat klingt für mich bizarr. Ebenso würde ich sagen, dass der Tag für die Emanzipation der Frau steht, nicht für die Unterdrückung, bzw. auch hier wiederum nur indirekt, da letzteres ersteres vorraussetzt. Außerdem wissen auch viele Frauen nicht, wann dieser Tag ist.

Comment: @user unknown: Wenn ich sage _»hat seinen Ursprung in«_, meine ich, dass Unterdrückung und Benachteiligung der Grund für die Existenz dieses Tages sind. Das ist doch nicht bizarr, bizarr ist anders. Aber dass auch viele Frauen dieses Datum nicht kennen, unterschreibe ich sofort, die Geburtstage von Justin Bieber & Co. sind wichtiger.

Comment: Ich meine, dass es keinen Automatismus von der Unterdrückung zum Frauentag gibt. Der Tag ist von denen, die sich gegen die Unterdrückung wenden begründet worden - der Satz mit dem Ursprung suggeriert das Gegenteil.

Comment: @user unknown: Aus der Verwendung von _»beglückwünschen«_ und _»deplatziert«_ geht hervor, dass das von dir genannte Gegenteil nicht gemeint sein kann.

Answer (score 8):

You could use:

- Alles Gute zum Frauentag/Weltfrauentag/...
- Alles Liebe zum Frauentag/...
- Ich wünsche Dir/Ihnen einen schönen Frauentag...

In my experience though, in Germany, this day is celebrated more as a day for women rights than as anything else.

Outside of feminists, communists, labour unions and the like, the day is perhaps best known among people from the former GDR and immigrants from East European countries such as Poland and Russia, where it was/is celebrated as a day for women.

In any case you might run into all kind of reactions with wishes for the "Frauentag": surprise, appreciation, disapprovement (rarely)... Few women would expect any wishes, but if you say it honestly or jokingly (like you might say "Happy Star Wars day"; May 4) you should not run into trouble.